# Nodejs react cannot get data on frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get all user data from the backend to display on the webpage. However, the getAllUsers() seems to not send back a response as the console.logs are not printed out.

Here is my ViewUsers.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AdminServices from "../Services/AdminServices";
import "././ViewUsers.css"

const ViewUsersComponent = (users) => {

    return (
        <div className="viewusers">
            <h1>All users</h1>
            <div className="viewusers-list">
                {users.map((user) => {
                    return (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <p> <b>Name</b> : {user.username} </p>
                        <p> <b>Email</b> : {user.email} </p>
                        <p> <b>Website role</b> : {user.websiteRole} </p>
                        <hr />
                    </React.Fragment>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default class ViewUsers extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.retrieveUsers = this.retrieveUsers.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            users: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.retrieveUsers();
    }

    retrieveUsers() {
        AdminServices.getAllUsers()
            .then(response => {
                if (response && response.data) {
                    this.setState({
                        users: response.data
                    });
                }
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log('DATA RECEIVED')
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log('ERROR')
                console.log(e); 
            });
    }

    render () {
        const { users } = this.state;
        console.log(users)

        if (Array.isArray(users) && users.length) {
            return ViewUsersComponent(users)
        } else {
            return (
                window.location = '/notfound'
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This is the AdminServices.js

```
import http from "../http-common"

class AdminServices {
    getAllUsers() {
        return http.get("/users");
    }

    getAllProjects() {
        return http.get("/projects");
    }
}

export default new AdminServices();
```

And the http-common.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8080",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include",
    withCredentials: true
});
```

And the userRoute.js

```
const express = require('express');

const User = require('../models/user').userModel;

const userRouter = express.Router();

// get all users
userRouter.get('/', async (req, res) => { 
  try {
    console.log("loading users")
    users = await User.find();
    if (users == null) {
      res.status(404).json({ message: "users not found" });
    }
    res.send(users);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});
```

When I send a get request to the user route via rest api, it works so I am not sure why it does not go through on the frontend

Comment: You get `/users` but only have a route handler for `/`. If that's inside a router, why are you checking `response.data`? Have you logged what `response` is?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add the code below to the one in the post
I used this in my app.js so the '/' in UserRoute would be '/users'
const usersRouter = require('./routes/UserRoute');
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

Comment: I tried logging response but there was nothing displayed in the console

Answer (score -1):

Please add CORS on backend project. You can configure the UI domain or use ‘*’ to allow all domain.

Comment: Yes, I added cors 
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: "http://localhost:3000"
}));